# applicationBadgeNumber not setting

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've sterted an app with 1 view controller. in the app delegate i want to shedule a notification for 1 minutes time after the app is launched

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[phil_croweViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"phil_croweViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval secondsInEightHours = 60;
    NSDate *dateOneMinsAhead = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];

    timeInTwoMinutes = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateOneMinsAhead dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotif.fireDate = dateOneMinsAhead;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"alert";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    NSLog(@"alert scheduled");


    return YES;
}
```

this works fine apart from the applicationBadgeNumber does not appear showing 1. Am i miss understanding what applicationBadgeNumber does? it is the red circle with the number in it??

Comment: check your notifications settings have not disabled badges.

Comment: this is in the simulator, when i go to settings in simulator theres no notification settings

Comment: where do i find 'device' in simulator?

Comment: check application in device and go through my answer

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the "Badge App Icon" setting for your app is not turned on in the new Notification Center.

[image]

Go to Settings > Notifications. Find your app either in "In Notification Center" section or "Not In Notification Center" section, and tap on it. Then turn on the "Badge App Icon" setting. p/s: it doesn't matter if you app is not in notification center (i.e. Notification Center = OFF); the badge icon setting does take effect

Comment: thanks but see comments on first answer. The simulator doesnt give these options

Comment: utimatly application is run on device

Comment: make "Badge App Icon" setting and run application in device problem will be solved